# How to transfer files between two hosts through a bastion using netcat and pigz

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, pipe, netcat

I have to regularly transfer the contents of folders containing a lot of small files with a volume of around 10GB from one server to another. Before I used the command bellow which did the job very well with an amazing speed! :

- hostA : tar -cf - | pigz | pv | nc -l 1111
- hostB : nc 1111| pigz -d | pv | tar xf - -C /tmp

But now, we will have to secure flow between these two hosts and I need to pass through a "bastion" server (admin server) so now I need to find a way to do the same thing but with an intermediate host...

hostA <------> hostX ----> hostB

If someone have a trick to do that, I have made some search and try to do it with scp but it is too slow.. And a definitivly prefer the speed with NC. Can we do this with netcat directly ? I couldn't find anything.

Or maybe if not possible using fully nc, can i combine nc and ssh tunneling ?

(Iam aware about the non security of this method)

Thanks in advance for your help.